# Alternate method to splice function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am working on LIME programming which is a subset of javascript.

i need to use javascript.splice to remove certain elements from my array, sad to say, LIME does not support splice function.

Any idea how do i create my own function to remove elements from an array?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Manage to create a simple function.

```
function removeElements(array, index)
{
    var tempArray = new Array();
    var counter = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(i != index)
        {
            tempArray[counter] = array[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Lightweight interactive multimedia environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Array.prototype.splice is fully defined in ECMA-262 §15.4.4.12, so use that as your spec and write one. e.g.

> #### 15.4.4.12 Array.prototype.splice (start, deleteCount [ , item1 [ ,item2 [ , … ] ] ] )
>
> When the splice
> method is called with two or more
> arguments *start*, *deleteCount* and
> (optionally) *item1*, *item2*, etc., the
> *deleteCount* elements of the array
> starting at array index *start* are
> replaced by the arguments *item1*,
> *item2*, etc. An Array object containing
> the deleted elements (if any) is
> returned. The following steps are
> taken:...

You will probably have to create a new array, copy the members up to *start* from the old array, insert the new members, then copy from *start* + *deleteCount* to the end to the new array.

#### Edit

Here is an amended splice, the first I posted was incorrect. This one splices the array passed in and returns the removed members. It looks a bit long but I tried to keep it close to the spec and not assume support for any complex Array methods or even *Math.max/min*. It can be simplified quite a bit if they are.

If push isn't supported, it can be replaced fairly simply too.

```
function arraySplice(array, start, deleteCount) {
  var result = [];
  var removed = [];
  var argsLen = arguments.length;
  var arrLen = array.length;
  var i, k;

  // Follow spec more or less
  start = parseInt(start, 10);
  deleteCount = parseInt(deleteCount, 10);

  // Deal with negative start per spec
  // Don't assume support for Math.min/max
  if (start < 0) {
    start = arrLen + start;
    start = (start > 0)? start : 0;
  } else {
    start = (start < arrLen)? start : arrLen;
  }

  // Deal with deleteCount per spec
  if (deleteCount < 0) deleteCount = 0;

  if (deleteCount > (arrLen - start)) {
    deleteCount = arrLen - start;
  }

  // Copy members up to start
  for (i = 0; i < start; i++) {
    result[i] = array[i];
  }

  // Add new elements supplied as args
  for (i = 3; i < argsLen; i++) {
    result.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  // Copy removed items to removed array
  for (i = start; i < start + deleteCount; i++) {
    removed.push(array[i]);
  }

  // Add those after start + deleteCount
  for (i = start + (deleteCount || 0); i < arrLen; i++) {
    result.push(array[i]);
  }

  // Update original array
  array.length = 0;
  i = result.length;
  while (i--) {
    array[i] = result[i];
  }

  // Return array of removed elements
  return removed;
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you, I was able to use this to solve a coding challenge and am now reviewing it to better understand what is going on

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about order of the array and you're just looking for a function to perform splice, here's an example.

```
/**
 * Time Complexity: O(count) aka: O(1)
 */
function mySplice(array, start, count) {
  if (typeof count == 'undefined') count = 1

  while (count--) {
    var index2remove = start + count
    array[index2remove] = array.pop()
  }

  return array
}
```

If you want to return the removed elements like the normal splice method does this will work:

```
/**
 * Time Complexity: O(count) aka: O(1)
 */
function mySplice(array, index, count) {
  if (typeof count == 'undefined') count = 1

  var removed = []

  while (count--) {
    var index2remove = index + count
    removed.push(array[index2remove])
    array[index2remove] = array.pop()
  }
  // for (var i = index; i < index + count; i++) {
  //    removed.push(array[i])
  //    array[i] = array.pop()
  // }

  return removed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implement in case the Array.prototype.splice dispears

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.splice === 'undefined') {
    Array.prototype.splice = function (index, howmany, elemes) {
        howmany = typeof howmany === 'undefined' || this.length;
        var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2), newArr = this.slice(0, index), last = this.slice(index + howmany);
        newArr =  newArr.concat.apply(newArr, elems);
        newArr =  newArr.concat.apply(newArr, last);
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This modifies the original Array, and returns the items that were removed, just like the original.

```
Array.prototype.newSplice = function( start, toRemove, insert ) {
    var remove = this.slice( start, start + toRemove );
    var temp = this.slice(0,start).concat( insert, this.slice( start + toRemove ) );
    this.length = 0;
    this.push.apply( this, temp );
    return remove;
};
```

**Comparison test:** http://jsfiddle.net/wxGDd/

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var arr2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];


console.log( arr.splice( 3, 2, 6 ) );      // [3, 4]
console.log( arr );      // [0, 1, 2, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8]

console.log( arr2.newSplice( 3, 2, 6 ) );  // [3, 4]
console.log( arr2 );     // [0, 1, 2, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It could use a little extra detail work, but for the most part it takes care of it.

Comment: Nice, but if *splice* isn't support then other methods might not be either. Might also be worth pointing out issues with adding properties to built-in prototypes (extra enumerated properties in for..in). Also, does it deal with negative *start* and *deleteCount* arguments?

Comment: @RobG: Yes you're right, it doesn't deal with a few details *(that's the extra detail work I mentioned)*. With respect to the other methods, I just have no idea so it could very well be that they're not available. And for the `for-in` issue, yes I probably should've mentioned it, but then we shouldn't `for-in` an Array anyway. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other methods that are missing in LIME's Array implementation?

Assuming at least the most basic `push()` and `indexOf()` is available, there's several ways you could do it.  How this is done would depend on whether this is destructive method or whether it should return a new array.  Assuming the same input as the standard `splice(index, howMany, element1, elementN)` method:

1. Create a new array named `new`
2. `push()` indexes 0 to `index` onto the `new` array
3. Now stop at `index` and `push()` any new elements passed in. If LIME supports the standard `arguments` variable then you can loop through `arguments` with index > 2. Otherwise you'll need to pass in an array instead of a variable number of parameters.
4. After inserting the new objects, continue looping through the input array's elements, starting at `index + howMany` and going until `input.length`

I believe that should get you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this below `function` as an alternative for `splice()`

```
array = mySplice(array,index,count);
```

above is the function call,
And this is my function `mySplice()`

```
 function mySplice(array, index, count)
{    
    var newArray = [];
    if( count > 0 ) 
        { count--;}
    else
        { count++;}
    for(i = 0; i <array.length; i++)
        {
            if(!((i <= index + count && i >=  index) || (i <= index && i >=  index + count)))  
            {
               newArray.push(array[i])
            }            
        }      
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it very similar way using only one for loop

```
function removeElements(a,index,n){
  // a=> Array , index=> index value from array to delete
 // n=> number of elements you want to delete
   let temp = []; // for storing deleted elements
   let main_array = []; // for remaining elements which are not deleted
   let k = 0;
   for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      if((i===index) || ((index<i && i<n+index))){
      temp[i]=a[i+1];
      delete a[i];
       }
    if(a[i]!==undefined){
      main_array[k] = a[i]; 
      a[i] = main_array[k];
       k++;
       }
     }

      a=main_array;
   return a;
   }
  a=[1,2,3,4,5];
  console.log(removeElements(a,0,1));
```

follow link [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnsj1tj3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [3, 2, 5, 6, 7];
var fromindex = 1
var toindex = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    if (i >= fromindex + toindex || i < fromindex) {
        console.log(a[i])
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = [3, 2, 5, 6, 7];
var temp=[];

function splice(fromindex,toindex)
{

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

       if(i>=fromindex+toindex || i<fromindex)
       {
        temp.push(a[i])
       }
     
    }
    return temp
  
}
console.log(splice(3,2))
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful with some **explanation**. Explain what it does, and how it's **different / better** than existing answers.